# How to change keyboard language programmatically in windows 8

Tags: localization, keyboard, windows-8.1, winjs

I need to change keyboard language (on screen keyboard) of windows 8.1 tablet (e.g. from English to Japanese-Katakana) based on some software conditions. Obviously the languages (and the keyboards) are pre-configured on the tablet.

Is possible to do this programmatically in WinJS?

Thanks, 
f.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I could find for what you are wanting to do.

From what I can tell, you've already done this first step, so skip it if you have, but take a quick look as its pretty nicely formatted and easy to follow if you haven't.

Do this first: " http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/using-multiple-languages "

and Now try this step below to change the language and make a easy way to switch between languages: " http://www.techtolead.com/how-to-add-a-new-language-in-windows-8-input-method/ "

and watch this quick video tutorial that demonstrates how to quickly switch between the desired languages for the onscreen keyboard. " h ttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5D2LjetRs5E " (just remove the space between the "h" and the "t" in  https.)

I take no credit for any of these tutorials, just found these and hope they help you. If you have any further questions or if I'm not fully understanding what you are trying to do, let me know and I'll be glad to try and help and learn some more.

Comment: Ok thanks for tutorials, but I need to do this by WinJS code, in a Worklight/Mobilefirst App...

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, makes sense, I missed that part. Let me see what I can scrounge up.